# Getting error while using Angular Form Array

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

Why am I getting this error, and how to get it fixed:
TS2740: Type 'AbstractControl<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'FormGroup': controls, registerControl, addControl, removeControl, and 2 more.

At this point it is giving error in my html:
[image]

my html:

```
<button type="button" (click)="addName()">Add Name</button>

<div formArrayName="names">
    <div *ngFor="let nm of getNames.controls">
        <div [formGroup]="nm"> //THIS LINE IS GIVING ERROR
            <input formControlName="fname" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
            <input formControlName="lname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 

<div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

my ts:

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {     
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

    form = this.fb.group({
        names: this.fb.array([])
    });

    get getNames(){
        return this.form.controls["names"] as FormArray;
    }

    addName(){
        const newName = this.fb.group({
            fname: ['', Validators.required],
            lname: ['', Validators.required]
        });
        this.getNames.push(newName);
    }

    onSubmit():void{
        console.log(this.form.value)
    }

   ngOnInit(): void {

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved by using $any in html as below.

```
<div *ngFor="let nm of  $any(getName).controls; let i=index">
```

Answer (score 0):

hi i us this way try it

```
 <div *ngFor="let nm of  getName.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?